# Can you tell me the name and location of post war camp in the Netherlands

Tags: world-war-two, post-war, netherlands

My father was a young Dutchman who was sent to Berlin to work for AEG as forced labour. According to my fathers account after the end of the war on  his return in Holland he was put in a camp in Harlem for about 3–6 weeks.   It was in a historic stone and cement building that possibly used to be an old military barracks.

He was there for about 3–4 weeks while he was investigated if he was a collaborator. He was freed after that time.

Would anybody know the name and location of the camp?

Comment: Thank you very much LangLangC- that matches his description precisely. You have solved a family mystery.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't seem to be one of the larger camps, listed in [Prison camps in the Netherlands](https://www.kamparchieven.nl/en/camps-in-the-netherlands). Although especially [Kamp Erica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp_Erika) near Ommen might give you quite a glimpse of the conditions in general after the war in these camps.

In Haarlem, there was the much smaller, former garrison-turned-internment-camp: *Koudenhorn* (~Coldhorn).

This is found mentioned quite briefly in a report about mostly scandalous conditions in Dutch camps after the war:

> In de „Koudehorn" te Haarlem konden bewakers zich af en toe vermaken (winter 1946) door de gevangenen beurtelings onder kokend en dan onder ijskoud water te plaatsen — een soort personeelscabaret.
>   __In the "Koudehorn" in Haarlem, guards could occasionally entertain themselves  (winter 1946) by alternately placing the prisoners under boiling and then under ice-cold water –– a kind of personnel cabaret.
>
> <sub>Hendrik Willem van der Vaart Smit: "Kamptoestanden 1944 45 48", N.V. Uitgeverij Keizerskroon - Haarlem, 1949. ([Scan on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Kamptoestanden1944-45-48))</sub>

The location seems to be listed in this Wikipedia stub as 
[Koudenhorn Kazerne](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koudenhorn_Kazerne), 52° 23′ 3″ NB, 4° 38′ 26″ OL ([Kaart](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koudenhorn_Kazerne#)).

A slighty later picture to confirm?

> [image]

That it was used for interrogating suspected political prisoners ([Bewarings- en Verblijfkamp](http://www.stelling-amsterdam.nl/stelling/extra/kampen/index.php)) after the war is confirmed here: [Haarlem Koudenhornkazerne](http://www.stelling-amsterdam.nl/kazernes/haarlem-koudenhornkazerne/).